# How to make a dialog show at the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, xml

How can I make a dialog (like in the figure) that shows after clicking a button? The dialog should appear at the bottom of the screen and its width should match the width of screen.

[click here to view the dialog figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VyrU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use onClick at xml to handle button click. You can write xml like this

```
<Button
    android:onClick = dialogShow() />
```

Than on your activity write function as

```
public void dialogShow(){
    //call next activity or whatever you like to do during button click
}
```

You can use layout to position dialog to button of the screen and use

```
android:layout_width = "match_parent"
```

in your dialog or layout to fill the width of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

or Use [BottomDialogs](https://github.com/javiersantos/BottomDialogs)